# Add token field in text editor (using Ckeditor) in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am developing an application in angular 2 using [ng2-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin/) template, I want to add token field in text editor (using CKEditor - Standard 4.6.0 version)

In detail -

I want to add a custom tag( span, button, anyone) to the editor with the cross button(x) like token field through a click event, So if the user wants to delete then the whole custom tag will delete rather than deleting any character between the custom tag.

I have tried to add a custom tag on click event but editor erases custom tag with a paragraph tag. Suggest me any approach to do the same.

[image]

Above Image is the screenshot of my application here I want to add a token field by clicking on the button which you can see in the image, After clicking on "name" button "Name" token field has added to the editor.

Here is my code, 
component.ts

```
tagClick(name){
    this.model.template += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">' + name + '</button>';
  }
```

template

```
<button class="btn" type="button" (click)="tagClick(name)" >{{name}}</button>
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="model.template" name="template" [config]="config"></ckeditor>
```

Comment: Have you *tried* to do this and ***failed***?  What parts worked? What parts didn't work?  This question doesn't read like a problem, it reads like a requirements list.

Comment: Also, don't add tags for frameworks not in use.  Angularjs and Angular2 **are not the same framework**.

Comment: now it's ok @Claies ?

Comment: do you have any code showing your click event?

Comment: I am just appending the Tag to the content of the editor, Wait I'll share that also. @Claies